# Inertia VueJS triggering the input file click event from a separate button

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am trying to trigger an event from button to input file. Below is the code

```
<template>
    <div>
        <PrimaryButton
            type="button"
            :for="props.videoId"
            :disabled="uploading"
            @click="selectVideo"
        >
        Upload
        </PrimaryButton>
        <input
            :hidden="true"
            :ref="videoInput"
            :id="props.videoId"
            type="file"
            @change="handleVideoLoad" // for emits
            :disabled="uploading"
        />
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import PrimaryButton from "@/Components/PrimaryButton.vue";
import { nextTick, ref } from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
    videoId: {
        type: String,
        default: () => "video-id",
    },
});
const uploading = ref(false);
const videoInput = ref(null);
const videoUrl = ref("");

const selectVideo = () => {
    videoInput.value = null;
    nextTick(() => {
        videoInput.value.click(); 
        // expecting this to trigger the click event of the videoInput but getting 
        // 「Cannot read properties of null (reading 'click') error」
    });
};
const handleVideoLoad = (event) => {
    ...  // some code
}
</script>
```

I believe I can use `document.getElementById` as the easiest solution but I want to do this the vue way. I am using Laravel Vue3 composition api

Answer (score 0):

[Template ref](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs#template-refs) should be given the **string** name of a `ref` variable

```html
<input ref="videoInput" ... />
```

Do not bind the ref with `:` by doing `:ref="videoInput"`

Also your function `selectVideo` needs corrections.  First thing you do is assign null to `videoInput.value` and then attempt to call the `click` function, which obviously won't work when you just made it `null`. Remove this assignment.

The other correction is that this function is not a valid use case for [nextTick](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick). It's not needed, so remove it. This is all your function needs to be:

```js
const selectVideo = () => {
    videoInput.value.click(); 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use refs if you want to just trigger the onchange event. What you need is to use [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label):

> ... The label text is not only visually associated with its corresponding text input; it is programmatically associated with it too ...

You could write your code this way:

```
<template>
...
    <!-- label can be loaded as component here -->
    <label 
        :class="{ disabled: uploading }"
        :for="props.videoId"
    > ... 
    </label>
    <!-- -->
    <input
        type="file"
        :id="props.videoId"
        :style="{ display: 'none' }"
        :disabled="uploading"
        @change="handleVideoLoad" // for emits
    />
</div>
</template>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
    videoId: {
        type: String,
        default: () => "video-id",
    },
});

const uploading = ref(false);
const handleVideoLoad = (event) => {
    ...  // some code
}
</script>
```